# Let $D_n=\{\alpha\in\mathbb{F}:|\alpha|\leqslant1\}$. Let $X=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} D_n$. Then why $D$ is a metric space?

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $D_n=\{\alpha\in\mathbb{F}:|\alpha|\leqslant1\}$ for each $n$. Let $X=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} D_n$. Then why $D$ is a metric space? This is from one theeorem in Conway's book. But I don't understand why X is a metric space.
[image]
Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, what is F?

Comment: @Giuseppe Barbaro $\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Your $D_n$ don't seem to have any dependence on $n$; as it stands, they're all identical. Is that by design? (Also, is the question trying to understand what metric one can impose on the space, or why some particular unspecified metric is actually a metric?)

Comment: @Steven Stadnicki Yes.

Comment: How do you define a metric on a twofold product, i.e. on $D_n \times D_n$?  can you generalize?

Comment: @XanderHenderson I don't know. This is a part of the prove in Conway's book.

Answer (score 1):

More generally, if $\{(D_n,d_n)\}$ is a sequence of metric spaces and $D:=\prod_{n=1}^\infty D_n$, then $D$ under the Tychonoff topology is metrizable. An example of such a metric is
$$d(x,y):=\sum_{n=1}^\infty2^{-n}\frac{d_n(x_n,y_n)}{1+d_n(x_n,y_n)}.$$
If each $D_n$ is compact, then $D$ is compact by Tychonoff's theorem.

Comment: In this situation, is $d_n$ for all n the same?

Comment: @AnswerLee Yeah, in your definition each $d_n$ is the same: just the euclidean distance on the unit interval.

Answer (score 0):

The space $D$ is a product of compact Hausdorff spaces and so is a compact Hausdorff space by Tychonov's theorem.

A corollary of the Urysohn Metrization theorem states that a compact Hausdorff space is metrizable if and only if is second countable, i.e. has a countable basis of neighborhoods. Can you check whether $D$ is second countable?

Comment: But how to get D is metric space?

Comment: @AnswerLee Metrizable means that the topology is induced from a metric. This theorem demonstrates the existence of a metric space structure on your $D$ if you can simply show that it is second countable.